# Android Studio Kotlin error on Toast message Outside of the onCreate Function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, webview, toast

I am getting errors on my toast message with the following:

```
    // JS FUNCTIONS FOR THE WEBVIEW
    private fun loadJs(webView: WebView) {
        webView.loadUrl(
        """javascript:(function f() {
                var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
                for (var i = 0, n = btns.length; i < n; i++) {
                  if (btns[i].getAttribute('id') === 'testBTN') {
                    btns[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'Android.onClicked()');
                  }
                }
              })()
            """
        )
    }

    // KOTLIN FUNCTIONS THAT JS CAN CALL
    object AndroidJSInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun onClicked() {
            Utils.showToast("in the js")
            Log.i("MK", "JS BUTTON CLICKED")
        }
    }
    /*
    * ##############################################################################################
    */

    object Utils {
        fun showToast(msg: String?, ctx: Context = MainActivity().applicationContext) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

The above codes listen to button clicks of my webview, the Log.i do give me results when I press my targeted button. The toast gives me an error.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

What is the best method to call the applicationContext in this manner?
I am coding this in Android Studio Kotlin

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `MainActivity()` Why are you instantiating the activity by yourself?

Comment: Hi @AnimeshSahu, thank you for the reply, what would be the best way to set what context to use in this manner? I have tried passing it with the loadJS function call but have been getting the same error